# Are JGL and JAL part of JDK?

Tags: java, algorithm, data-structures

I am new to Java, and looking for standard data structure and algorithm libraries in Java.

By googling, I bumped into [JGL](http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?JavaGenericLibrary)
and 
[JAL](http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?JavaAlgorithmLibrary).
I find most discussion of them are several years old such as http://www4.ncsu.edu/~kaltofen/courses/Languages/JavaExamples/jgl3.1.0/doc/index.html. yet, JGL seems to have a new site http://www.recursionsw.com/products/JGL/JGL-collections-and-algorithms.html, while I haven't found out about JAL (maybe JAL has been incorporated into JGL?).

Are they part of JDK, just like Java collections in JDK?

I wonder if they are used, and in what cases they are better than Java collections? Thanks.

Comment: No and no. This should be obvious from the home-page links. Neither of them is a Sun or Oracle link. IMO it is curious that anyone would think anything based on C++ STL superior to anything.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, the JGL and JAL are not part of the JDK. Both are very old, and very outdated (For example, the last change to the Colt library, in the JAL was over 10 years ago!). The Java Collections are far superior to the JGL.

> Those who believe JGL to be superior to Java Collections are very
>   wrong. I did exhaustive performance comparisons when the Collections
>   API was added to Java, and it beat the pants off of JGL. It wasn't
>   even close. As to whether JGL was superior in design, well, de
>   gustibus non est disputandum. JGL was much larger, and had a much
>   lower power-to-weight ratio, but it was more familiar to those versed
>   in STL.
>   -- *Josh Bloch*

If you need implementations of common mathematical algorithms for Java, I'd suggest you look into the [Apache Commons Math library](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-math/). If you want more advanced Java collections, look into [Google's Guava](https://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/) library (however the default Java collections are quite good).

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at [fastutil](http://fastutil.di.unimi.it/), it is interoperable with `java.util` collections, has primitive specializations for performance and includes algorithms which are not implemented in JDK, namely AVL trees, big lists (lists of > 2 bln size) and array maps.